# EIGRP redistribute static issue

Tags: cisco, eigrp

I have an EIGRP issue hopefully someone can help me with. I have a 2821 router with three static routes to VLANs that exist on a switch it's connected to. I want to share these routes with the rest of my network. I thought a "redistribute static" command would do this, but it does not.

I can run a "show ip eigrp topology  " on the router and other equipment in the eigrp network and the network information comes up, but I can't ping any of the VLANs from anything but the router. My EIGRP statement also includes "no auto-summary" but that does not help either. Below is the results of the "show ip eigrp topology" command.

```
router#sh ip eigrp XXX top 10.X.47.0 255.255.255.0
IP-EIGRP (AS XXX): Topology entry for 10.X.47.0/24
State is Passive, Query origin flag is 1, 1 Successor(s), FD is 28160
Routing Descriptor Blocks:
10.X.0.15, from Rstatic, Send flag is 0x0
Composite metric is (28160/0), Route is External
  Vector metric:
    Minimum bandwidth is 100000 Kbit
    Total delay is 100 microseconds
    Reliability is 255/255
    Load is 1/255
    Minimum MTU is 1500
    Hop count is 0
  External data:
    Originating router is 10.X.X.3 (this system)
    AS number of route is 0
    External protocol is Static, external metric is 0
    Administrator tag is 0 (0x00000000)
```

Comment: What is the `router eigrp` configuration?

Comment: Thanks for everybody's replies so far. After assessing the situation further, it looks like the switch the router is attached to (3750-X) should be able to do full EIGRP. I've added an EIGRP statement to the switch, matched the EIGRP numbers, and the switch and router can ping each other, yet they won't become neighbors.

I've run through the "neighbor check" section on the support document below and I'm at the "your problem is not a common problem" block.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/enhanced-interior-gateway-routing-protocol-eigrp/21324-trouble-eigrp.html#nc

Comment: You should post an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you redistributed static without setting a metric.  By default, routes redistributed into EIGRP have a metric of "unreachable".

You either need to specify a metric for the static routes in your "redistribute static" command, or you need to specify a default metric using the "default-metric" command.

Answer (score 0):

After examining my switch closer I've discovered I can run full EIGRP on it so I won't need to statically redistribute routes from the router.

Comment: Accept your answer so that this question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.